# Using ArcPy to iterate feature classes for kriging

Tags: arcpy, loop, iterator, kriging

I have 12 feature classes and they are named from `net_0` to `net_11` but the order of feature classes In Arc catalog is,`List_wells = [net_0,net_1,net_10,net_11,net_2,net_3,net_4,net_5,..net_9]`.
I used this code to kriging each feature class and I would like every kriging raster to have it's feature classes's name.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/gis/Pychram_tabu/26try2/List_of_wells"
List_wells = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for x in range(len(List_wells)):
    inFeatures = List_wells[x]
    field = "EC"
    kriging = Kriging(inFeatures, field, modelordinary, cellsize, Kradius, "")
    kriging.save("E:/gis/Pychram_tabu/26try2/kriging/net_{}".format(x))
```

As you see for `x=2` my `inFeatures = net_10` but when the kriging raster is formed, it will take name `net=2`. how can I matching their name. Is It any way to sort arc catalog features numerical? I mean my List_wells in arc catalog be `[net_0,net_1,net_2,net_3,net_4,...net_11]`.

I put image of my arc catalog.

[image: arccatalog]

Comment: If you formatted your names with a leading zero for two digits of display, a sorted list would be in the desired order (`net_00`, `net_01`, `net_02`, ...). This is best practice. Python is a list-oriented language, and using `for x in range(len(List_wells))` is not as Pythonic as `for well in wells`. Learning a language includes learning the style, which includes naming conventions (lower_case for variables, UpperCase for classes) see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating things with range and indexing.

Use ListFeatureClasses like this:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/gis/Pychram_tabu/26try2/List_of_wells"

fieldname = "EC"
for well in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): #well will be a shapefile name for each iteration, for example 'net0.shp'
    krig = Kriging(in_point_features=well, z_field=fieldname, ... ) #I dont know how to specify model, I dont have Spatial Analyst
    result = os.path.join(r'C:\some\folder', well.replace('.shp','.tif'))
    krig.save(result)
```

Comment: @BERA.yes This solution Is what I was looking for .Thank you very much